# Merge two multidimensional list on a matching element in python

Tags: python, list, merge, concatenation

I am trying to merge two multidimensional list on a matching element. For example:

```
list1 = [['1', '2' ,'A'], ['3','4','D']]
list2 = [['A','A1'],['B','B1'],['C','C1'],['D','D1'],['D','D2']]
```

And the output I want is:

```
[['1', '2', 'A', 'A1'],['3', '4', 'D', 'D1'],['3', '4', 'D', 'D2']]
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Will the item to merge on always be at the end of a list in list1, and at the start of the list in list2?

Comment: In my case yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out = [ b + a[1:] for a in list2 for b in list1 if b[-1] == a[0] ]
print( out )
```

Output:

```
[['1', '2', 'A', 'A1'], ['3', '4', 'D', 'D1'], ['3', '4', 'D', 'D2']]
```

Comment: If I run this I get the output:

[['1', '2', 'A', 'A1'], ['3', '4', 'D', 'D1']]

without the  ['3', '4', 'D', 'D2']

Comment: Strange! For me it works fine. Here's a demo: https://trinket.io/python/7c38f22232 if that demo is working for you, there must be a difference in the code you're using and the code you've posted here to StackOverflow.